# D3.js .each() with function that passes data

Tags: d3.js

I would like to put my tooltip into a function such that I can re-use it for multiple elements. When I call the tooltip function for the label element the tooltip displays only the first x value to all labels instead of looping over the X value array. How do I properly access the data in the function?

```
const tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
     .attr('id', 'rect-tooltip');

function mouseover(data-x){
  d3.select('g')
  area.selectAll("text")
       .on('mouseover', (d) => {
       rect-tooltip.transition()
         .duration(100)
         .style('opacity', .9)
       rect-tooltip.html(`${data-x}`) //Pass in X-values
         .style('left', `${d3.event.pageX + 10}px`)
         .style('top', `${d3.event.pageY - 18}px`);
     })
     .on('mouseout', (d) => {
       rect-tooltip.transition()
         .duration(400)
         .style('opacity', 0);
     })

}  

const label = d3.select('g') 
      area.selectAll("text")
       .data(data)
       .join('text')
       .attr("class", "label")
       .text( (d)=> {return d.name;})
       .attr("x", (d)=> {return d.x;})
       .attr("y", (d)=> {return d.y;})
       .each(function(d) {
       mouseover(d.x);}); // Only first data point is added to each label?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an example of the this, I may be mis-reading your issue.

**Problem**

The key problem stems from iterating through the text elements twice:

```
area.each(function (d) { 
   // do something with each element/datum in the selection
})

d3.selectAll("text")     
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
  // apply an event listner and corrsesponding function to each text element.
})
```

The problem is you nest the second in the first. For every element in `area` you select all the `text` elements: if you have 2 elements you're selecting all the text twice. You only need to select each `text` element once.

In the pattern you have, for each element in `area` we pass that element's datum to the nested function which takes a property of that datum and with `d3.selectAll("text").on("mouseover" ...` applies that *single* datum to *all* `text` mouseover events. Since you do this for every element in `area`, we end up overwriting the event listeners multiple times.

No where do you reference the current datum in the chain following `d3.selectAll("text")`, so we only have a value from the current datum in the current iteration of `.each()`.

**Solution**

You shouldn't need to use `.each()` here to apply an event listener, `.on()` should be sufficient.

We have our mouseover and mouseout functions:

```
function mouseover(d) {
    tooltip
       .style("opacity", 0.9)
       .text(d.x)
       .style('left', `${d3.event.pageX + 10}px`)
       .style('top', `${d3.event.pageY - 18}px`);
}
function mouseout() {
   tooltip
     .style("opacity",0);
}
```

Then we can call it with:

```
selection.on("mouseover",mouseover) 
   .on("mouseout",mouseout);
```

And we can resuse this on multiple selections or elements. The datum specific to each element will be used to define the tooltip text.

```js
var tooltip = d3.select(".tooltip");
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = [{x: 10},{x:50},{x:90},{x:130},{x:170},{x:210},{x:250},{x:290},{x:330}]

var g = svg.selectAll(null)
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate("+[d.x,0]+")"; })
   
var rect = g.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 35)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr("fill","steelblue")
  .on("mousemove",mouseover)
  .on("mouseout",mouseout)
  
var text = g.append("text")
  .attr("y", 120)
  .attr("x", 18)
  .style("text-anchor","middle")
  .text(function(d) { return d.x; })
  .on("mouseover",mouseover)
  .on("mouseout",mouseout)  
   
function mouseover(d) {
    tooltip
       .style("opacity", 0.9)
       .text(d.x)
       .style('left', `${d3.event.pageX + 10}px`)
       .style('top', `${d3.event.pageY - 18}px`);
}
function mouseout() {
   tooltip
     .style("opacity",0);
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  background: yellow;
}

rect, text {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="tooltip"></div>
<svg width="400" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but how would it work if instead of d.x I would like to pass in d.y or any other data attribute? passing in .on("mouseout", mouseover(d.y)) does not work.

Comment: No, but you can pass a parameter with .on("mouseover", function(d) { mouseover(d.x); }) to pass part of the datum. If you just use .on("mouseover",mouseover), the whole datum is passed.

Comment: Thank you very much. That answers my question and solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Andrew his comment I changed my code to:

```
const tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
     .attr('id', 'tooltip');

 function mouseover(d){
  tooltip.transition()
        .duration(100)
        .style('opacity', .9)
  tooltip.html(d)
        .style('left', `${d3.event.pageX + 10}px`)
        .style('top', `${d3.event.pageY - 18}px`);
}

function mouseout(){
    tooltip.transition()
         .duration(400)
         .style('opacity', 0);
}  

const label = d3.select('g') 
      area.selectAll("text")
       .data(data)
       .join('text')
       .attr("class", "label")
       .text( (d)=> {return d.name;})
       .attr("x", (d)=> {return d.x;})
       .attr("y", (d)=> {return d.y;})
       .on("mouseover", function(d) { mouseover(d.x); })
       .on("mouseout", mouseout);
```